# Place password into program through VBA

Tags: vba, excel, passwords

I currently have the following code to open up a program (not a Microsoft Office program) in my macro.

```
   Dim x As Variant
   Dim Path As String
   Path = "Path of my program"
   x = Shell(Path, vbNormalFocus)
```

It then opens up a login window (where the username is saved) but I need to place the password? Is it possible to have a macro that will then type the password into this window?

The end goal is to eventually have a button/macro that opens the program, types in the password, and then pulls a data set from this non-Microsoft software.

Is any of that possible? How would I go about to doing that?

Thanks in advance for any and all help!

Comment: What is the software? It might have a COM library

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're asking for is ver insecure and undermines the protection and security enforced by the username and password requirement of your program. That being said, you should look into the [SendKeys](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff821075(v=office.15).aspx) macro action. `Application.SendKeys("+password")` would type `Password`, although you might have problems getting Excel to actually send the key presses to your other program. If that's the case then you'll need to reframe your question into one about automating login for whatever that other program is.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your best bet at interacting with a non-Microsoft software would be **AutoHotKey**. It's a free software with simple syntax that can automate any task you might want to.

You could make your script so it opens the software, enters your login, and then copy-pastes the information you need.

For added security (note that automatically entering a password is always a big security flaw), you can compile the resulting script into an executable so nobody can see the source code of your script.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Frédéric's right about the security flaw, and a fundamental design weakness is only ever going to be ameliorated by clever coding tricks - not fixed. For your reference, 'Compiled into an executable' isn't the same as 'encrypted'. Most of the time, it means 'I can read the static strings like plaintext with a binary text reader', and some of the time it means 'The compiler has a secure mode that uses a a moderately difficult hash function'. You have to regard the job you're doing as a 'courtesy lock' rather than 'secure'.- so check with the users that this is OK.